# Are these questions duplicates?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

[Why is Akame the center of attention?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/16761/why-is-akame-the-center-of-attention)

[What does 'Akame ga Kill' mean and why is it called that?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18739/what-does-akame-ga-kill-mean-and-why-is-it-called-that)

Actually the second one was posted because the first didn't get any attention. I think the second question (and its answer) successfully solves the first question.

Since the second one is of a higher quality and overlaps the first, I think the first should be closed.

Comment: The first question seems to be asking how/why was Akame made the protagonist whereas the second is fousing upon how the title came to be and what it implies. Moreover, the second was posted after the first. Therefore, in terms of originality the duplicate is the second . Not the first. Imo the second should be edited rather than closing the first.

Comment: @EroSɘnnin: We close duplicate based on whether the answers sufficiently answer the question we close as duplicate. The date of the question doesn't really matter.

Comment: @nhahtdh I see . .. Din't realise that. So closing one is an option.

Comment: @EroSɘnnin the scope of both questions, while there is some overlap, is different. One focuses on the characters, while the other focuses on the title. Essentially one is asking: "Why is the series named after her if she's not the main focus." The other asks: "What does the title of the series mean (and what does it have to do with Akame)?"